# How to implement a do...while with a BufferedReader input

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a simple calculator program, and the basic functionality works, but I'm trying to implement a "do you want to do another operation" at the the end of the program so that it closes if the answer isn't y. Says my "yesorno" can't be resolved to a variable

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    do {

        System.out.println("Enter 2 numbers");

        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int numero1=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        BufferedReader br2=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int numero2=Integer.parseInt(br2.readLine());

        System.out.println("Select an operation");

        BufferedReader br3=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        char Operacija=(char)br3.read();
        switch (Operacija)
        {
        case '+':
            System.out.println(numero1+numero2);
            break;
        case '-':
            System.out.println(numero1-numero2);
            break;
        case '/':
            System.out.println(numero1/numero2);
            break;
        case '*':
            System.out.println(numero1*numero2);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Illegal operation");
        }
        BufferedReader br4=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        char yesorno=(char)br4.read();
    }while (yesorno=='y');      




}}
```

Comment: It is a scope problem, declare this variable before the loop .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not valid : `while (yesorno='y');`
You assign a value to a variable while the `while` statement expects a boolean expression.
So you want to write : 
`while (yesorno=='y');`

And you don't need to create/declare so many `BufferedReader` objects since
they all use the same source : `System.in`.

So just declare and instantiate it once before the `do/while()`:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
char yesorno= 'y';

do {
    System.out.println("Enter 2 numbers");
    //...
}  
while (yesorno=='y');
```

And use that everywhere you need to read input from the standard input.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining `char yesorno` before you enter the loop:

**and refer to davidxxx: you need to use `==` instead of `=`**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    char yesorno = 'y';
    do {

        System.out.println("Enter 2 numbers");
    ...
    case '*':
            System.out.println(numero1*numero2);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Illegal operation");
        }
        BufferedReader br4=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        yesorno=(char)br4.read();
    }while (yesorno=='y'); 
    ...
...
```

Comment: @DomMikac it doesn't matter as long as you ask before the while, but you have to define it before entering the loop